# is it possible to create a HTML 4 Project in Netbeans 7.3 EE

Tags: html, ide, netbeans-7

As the question states, is it possible to create a HTML 4 Project in Netbeans 7.3 EE?

I can just go in and edit the DOCTYPE tag of each individual html file, but the project itself is still a HTML 5 project.

I was just wondering if it was possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the web like project you want (Java Web, HTML/JavaScript, Maven Web...) and in the created index.html (not sure now about JSP but should be the same) and delete the doctype definition and save the file. After that, there is a little bulb icon in the gutter (place with line numbers) at line 1. If you click on it, it offers you to change project's default doctype. Change it to whatever you want and from now on, NetBeans should use this doctype in new html-like files.

Comment: That you sir that's great! :)